# woocommerce my account customization

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to add a checkbox in my wocommerce registration page that, if checked, it redirects after a successful registration to an addition sign up page I have on my server. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: you should also show us your code.

Comment: meaning my php coding of my login.php for woocommerce?

Comment: meaning the code you've tried to use to achieve your goal